# Using iptables (or proxy) to whitelist certain web addresses

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, proxy

I am trying to set up a captive portal on an Ubuntu server machine.

I want to be able to route all traffic to my web app (same box) so they can register. Upon registration, the user's mac address gets added to an ipset which is then allowed to use the internet as normal.

My current iptables config is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Aliases
IPT=/sbin/iptables
IPS=/sbin/ipset

# Create sets
$IPS create whitelist hash:mac -exist

# Add whitelisted devices to set
$IPS add whitelist 00:11:22:33:44:55 -exist

# flush the iptables
$IPT -F

# Set up the iptables
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP

$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o WAN -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -A FORWARD -i LAN -o WAN -m set --match-set whitelist src,dst -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A FORWARD -i WAN -o LAN -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -p tcp -d bbc.co.uk -j ACCEPT

$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i LAN -m set ! --match-set whitelist src,dst -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.10

$IPT -A FORWARD -d 192.168.100.10 -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i LAN -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i WAN -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Now I want to always allow all users (wether registered or not) to access a website address (bbc.co.uk for example) - this needs to work over SSL (443) too.

I have tried to `$IPT -A OUTPUT -t tcp -d bbc.co.uk -j ACCEPT` but it didn't work

I have also seen a few people suggest not using iptables to target DNS addresses and to use squid proxy instead. I'm not sure I can achieve this using squid as I need to base my rules on the ipset I keep up to date with my web app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from what @user2563336's answer, I needed to add the following lines:

```
$IPT -A FORWARD -d $MYSERVER -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -d $MYSERVER -j ACCEPT
```

I also needed to allow DNS so that my hostname could be resolved

My full iptables script is:

```
#!/bin/sh


# Aliases
IPT=/sbin/iptables
IPS=/sbin/ipset


MYSERVER=myserver.com


# Create sets
$IPS create gold hash:mac -exist
$IPS create silver hash:mac -exist


# Add whitelisted devices to set
# $IPS add gold 00:11:22:33:44:55 -exist  # macbook air


# flush the tables
$IPT -F
$IPT -t nat -F


# Set up the iptables
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP


# Allow DNS
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


# whitelist MYSERVER
$IPT -A FORWARD -d $MYSERVER -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -d $MYSERVER -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  # this one


# Nat
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o WAN -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -A FORWARD -i WAN -o LAN -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i LAN -o WAN -m set --match-set gold src,dst -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i LAN -o WAN -m set --match-set silver src,dst -j ACCEPT


$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i LAN -m set ! --match-set gold src,dst -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.10
$IPT -A FORWARD -d 192.168.100.10 -j ACCEPT


$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i LAN -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use:

```
$IPT -A OUTPUT -t tcp -d bbc.co.uk -j ACCEPT
```

Why am I asking this?
First of all you are using FORWARD and PREROUTING rules to establish your filters. But now you are using a different table to enable the connection.
This will most likely not work as intended. See the [diagram at wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg).

As I understand your setup you disable the connection in the PREROUTING chain.
So the command to enable the connection would be:

```
$IPT -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -t tcp -d bbc.co.uk -j ACCEPT
```

In regards to your second question:
You already send unauthorized systems to your server. So you would have to configure any proxy to allow bbc.com as a special rule instead of redirecting it to your form.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe I'm getting further but I still don't have the solution (I'm fairly new to the iptables side of things). I added the line you suggested (using `-p tcp` though instead of `-t tcp`). 

I still don't have access to bbc.co.uk, as it times out (it doesn't redirect me). I believe this is due to me not allowing the incoming response, but I'm not too sure how to do this.